# Enable backspace shortcut for back in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-canary

It was with disbelief that I noticed Chromium has decided to [remove backspace to navigate back in browser history](https://codereview.chromium.org/1854963002), a shortcut which has been established almost universally across all browsers for decades.

This really, really irritates me as I navigate 'back' probably hundreds of times a day and backspace is by far the quickest way to do it.

I'm aware there are other options such as clicking the back button, Right click-> Back or Alt+Left, but all seem a little awkward for something as simple as going back.

Is there any way to enable the shortcut? Preferably without an extension?

Comment: They are working on getting a addon to fix it you can read about this [Here](http://arstechnica.com/business/2016/05/google-backspace-navigation-chrome-52/) for an alternate you could use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck/related?hl=en) to make an easier backspace. Until the fix is rolled out.

Comment: And I thought I despised Google before.. I can't believe they didn't offer an option